# Module not found: 'cldr' in ... \globalize\dist\globalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

In my React app, I am trying to use the `DateTimePicker` component included with the [`react-widgets` package](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/). I am also using Bootstrap 4 components via `reactstrap`.

I have installed the modules:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-beta reactstrap@next
npm install --save globalize react-widgets-globalize
```

but when I try to use the `DateTimePicker` component:

```
import Globalize from 'globalize'
import globalizeLocalizer from 'react-widgets-globalize'
import { DateTimePicker } from 'react-widgets'

class Foo extends Component {
    render() {

        Globalize.locale('en')
        globalizeLocalizer()
        let formatter = Globalize.dateFormatter({ raw: 'MMM dd, yyyy' })

        return(
            <div>
                <DateTimePicker
                    format={formatter} 
                    defaultValue={new Date()}
                    time={false}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I get the errors

```
Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist
 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js 22:2-25:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js 22:2-25:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js 22:2-26:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js 22:2-26:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js
Module not found: 'cldr/supplemental' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js
Module not found: 'cldr/supplemental' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js 22:2-27:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js 18:2-24:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js 18:2-24:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js
Module not found: 'cldr/supplemental' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js 18:2-24:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js 22:2-28:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js 22:2-28:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js
Module not found: 'cldr/supplemental' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js 22:2-28:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js 22:2-29:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js
Module not found: 'cldr/event' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js 22:2-29:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js
Module not found: 'cldr/supplemental' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js 22:2-29:14

Error in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/unit.js
Module not found: 'cldr' in C:\Users\y\Desktop\test\node_modules\globalize\dist\globalize

 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize/unit.js 22:2-27:14
```

What npm packages or configuration am I still missing?

Comment: have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/603)

Comment: @Sag1v Thanks for pointing it out. Tried `npm install --save globalize-webpack-plugin` but still getting the same error

Comment: @Nyxynyx what is your webpack config looking like  for the globalized plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing `node-modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Answer (score -1):

try: `npm i globalize`
I faced the same issue in angular and this solution works for me after checking doc https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize